# database manipulation, php and yii framework

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I am making a website using Yii framework and XAMPP. It's a part of the school project so we need to make some basic stuff. I used phpmyadmin as a tool to create a database which I use for this site. I generated relations between its tables and made some forms for entering data into the database on the site (e.g. like professors of the university, courses, etc). Now I would like to implement the option of informing the user of an error when he enters lets say the same professor (so basically wants to make a new database table with same contents).

I don't have any clue as to how to do this do I make it part of the code of the website or do I have to set up something in phpmyadmin, so any sort of help is welcome.

Comment: You have already created the CRUD operations  elements alias code for  Create, Read, Update, Delete, index/list..  Model Controller and View? Y  Which framework version you are using Yii1 or Yii2?

Comment: yes I've created everything you mentioned and I am using Yii2. But when I create a new table entry using that Create class I'd like for it to report an error if the table with those same entries already exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the validation rules in model

In this case you need a unique validator [(see this doc)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator.html)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        .....
        ['your_field', 'unique'],
        ... 
        ....
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... Now you can also rate the answer as useful  good work

Comment: is there a way I could make these validators work the following way, for example I want to schedule some classes on monday from 8 to 9, now as you suggested I can check if 8 is unique, but in this case I need to check if it is unique on this day. This table has all those propreties "from_time", "to_time", "day", etc. ?

Comment: Seems this is possibile look at the various (brief ) sample in doc in  ansewer .. seems is possibile use a set of field [['a1', 'a2'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['a1', 'a2']]

Comment: Just two suggestion .. for avoiding downvote to your next question . post some code of what you are trying to do .. (question without code frequently are downvoted).. if you use Yii2  add tag  yii2 too..

Comment: yeah I see that now thanks, I just didn't post any because I didn't know if it was code related at all or it had to be configured in the actual database, but I get what are you saying